# Objects are created but there is no movement in OOP Version

Tags: python, arrays, oop, physics, vpython

I'm coding a OOP Version of a solar system. When I run it, the objects are created, also the distances and the radius are correct. But the planets don't move. But I have a function, so they should go around the sun. I get an name error :  NameError: `name 'planetSphere' is not defined`. I tried it with deleting the def setspeed part. Then I can see with the prints that its working, because the numbers of the axis changes, but I can't see any change of the planets in the simulation itself. whole code: https://trinket.io/python/e2b520c570

```
 planets = []


class Sphere(object):
    def __init__(self, pos, radius, make_trail):
        self.pos = pos
        self.radius = radius
        self.make_trail = make_trail



class planet(Sphere):

    def __init__(self, pos, radius, make_trail, mass, velocity):
        super().__init__(pos, radius, make_trail)
        self.mass = mass
        self.velocity = velocity
        planetSphere = sphere (pos = self.pos, radius = self.radius, make_trail = self.make_trail, mass = self.mass, velocity = self.velocity)

    def setPosition(self, newPos ):
        planetSphere.pos = newPos
        print(planetSphere.pos)


sun = planet(pos=vec(0,0,0),radius=s_rad1*1.5, make_trail=True, mass=2e30, velocity=vec(0,0,0))

#Other objects

planets.extend((mercury,venus,earth,mars,jupiter,saturn,uranus,neptun,pluto))

dt = 10000
time = 0.1


while True:

    rate(framerate) 
    print(earth.pos)



    #for-Schlaufe für Berechnung jedes einzelnen Planeten


    for planet2 in planets:
        g_force = vec(0,0,0)
        for planet1 in planets:
            if planet2 != planet1:
                g_force += g * planet1.mass * planet2.mass * (planet1.pos - planet2.pos).norm()  / (planet1.pos - planet2.pos).mag2
        #print((sun.pos - planet.pos).mag2)




        #print(sun.pos)

        #Änderung des Velocity Vektor wird zum alten addiert
        #Da a=F/m // V = a*t(a*dt) 2 Geschw. vektoriell durch F/m ausgedrückt.
            planet2.velocity = planet2.velocity + ( (g_force) / planet2.mass) * 1000 #Richtungsänderung

        #Diese Änderung wird zur alten Position addiert = neue Position
            planet2.pos += planet2.velocity * 1000
            newPos = planet2.pos
            planet2.setPosition(newPos)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def setPosition():
    #planetSphere.pos = self.pos
    print(planetSphere.pos)
```

Is defined inside the planet class. So the first argument that the methods expects is "self".

Also, following the line of thought, this might be what you are looking for:

```
def setPosition(self,newPos):
    planetSphere.pos = newPos
    print(planetSphere.pos)
```

Comment: Ive taken your suggestions into the code. I don't get this error anymore but its still not working. Ive changed it in the code above and gave further explanations

Comment: Do not update the question on the run. People in the future may need the same info as you and come across an answer to a question that no longer exist. It is a site to provide clear answers to clear question, not to provide a constant support.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried in the init method of the planet class to make planetSphere => self.planetSphere? Here is what I mean:

```
class planet(Sphere):

def __init__(self, pos, radius, make_trail, mass, velocity):
    super().__init__(pos, radius, make_trail)
    self.mass = mass
    self.velocity = velocity
    self.planetSphere = sphere (pos = self.pos, radius = self.radius, make_trail = self.make_trail, mass = self.mass, velocity = self.velocity)

def setPosition(self, newPos ):
    self.planetSphere.pos = newPos
    print(planetSphere.pos)
```

Comment: Yes but the Planets are still not moving. Here I can give you my whole code. Perhaps then you see the problem better. https://trinket.io/python/e2b520c570

Comment: Hey, it won't let me run your code but try printing out your velocity because maybe it is 0 and you really aren't updating your position at all.